# Highcharts with multiple categories and multiple values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm looking for help on putting together a Highcharts chart. If you look at my JSON data which is a list of objects below the `TestCaseData` key I have two categories `SFA` and `IRB` I would like to group data into those categories and below that I have sub keys such as `SFA CASE 1, SFA CASE 2, SFA CASE 3` under those keys I would like to chart the `N_S` and `S_N`  `mean` values in the graph.

I have built a static version of what I am trying to do in a JSfiddle and attached a pic as well of kind of what I am looking to do. If any one could me on this it would be greatly appreciated.

I also have a JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/Lkbrnqyo/51/)

[image: pic]

```js
// this is what my JSON data object will look like
const myDataObj = [
    {
    "TestBedGeneralInfo" : {
        "date" : "04-02-2020",
    }, 
    "TestCaseData" : {
        "SFA" : {
            "SFA CASE 1" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 265.2864424458308, 
                    "min" : 145.63202330112372, 
                    "mean" : "218.29059492649517"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 15.744002519040402, 
                    "min" : 15.744002519040402, 
                    "mean" : "15.744002519040402"
                }
            }, 
            "SFA CASE 2" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 292.8384468541515, 
                    "min" : 149.56802393088384, 
                    "mean" : "220.65219530435124"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 16.137602582016413, 
                    "min" : 15.7440025190404, 
                    "mean" : "15.980162556826008"
                }
            }, 
            "SFA CASE 3" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 261.74404187904673, 
                    "min" : 142.48322279731565, 
                    "mean" : "197.68563162970105"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 14.563202330112372, 
                    "min" : 14.169602267136362, 
                    "mean" : "14.327042292326766"
                }
            },
        }
    }
}, {
    "TestBedGeneralInfo" : {
        "date" : "04-02-2020",
    }, 
    "TestCaseData" : {
        "IRB" : {
            "IRB CASE 1" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 265.2864424458308, 
                    "min" : 145.63202330112372, 
                    "mean" : "218.29059492649517"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 15.744002519040402, 
                    "min" : 15.744002519040402, 
                    "mean" : "15.744002519040402"
                }
            }, 
            "IRB CASE 2" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 292.8384468541515, 
                    "min" : 149.56802393088384, 
                    "mean" : "220.65219530435124"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 16.137602582016413, 
                    "min" : 15.7440025190404, 
                    "mean" : "15.980162556826008"
                }
            }, 
            "IRB CASE 3" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 261.74404187904673, 
                    "min" : 142.48322279731565, 
                    "mean" : "197.68563162970105"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 14.563202330112372, 
                    "min" : 14.169602267136362, 
                    "mean" : "14.327042292326766"
                }
            },
        }
    }
    }, {
    "TestBedGeneralInfo" : {
        "date" : "04-02-2020",
    }, 
    "TestCaseData" : {
        "SFA" : {
            "SFA CASE 1" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 265.2864424458308, 
                    "min" : 145.63202330112372, 
                    "mean" : "218.29059492649517"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 15.744002519040402, 
                    "min" : 15.744002519040402, 
                    "mean" : "15.744002519040402"
                }
            }, 
            "SFA CASE 2" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 292.8384468541515, 
                    "min" : 149.56802393088384, 
                    "mean" : "220.65219530435124"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 16.137602582016413, 
                    "min" : 15.7440025190404, 
                    "mean" : "15.980162556826008"
                }
            }, 
            "SFA CASE 3" : {
                "N_S" : {
                    "max" : 261.74404187904673, 
                    "min" : 142.48322279731565, 
                    "mean" : "197.68563162970105"
                }, 
                "S_N" : {
                    "max" : 14.563202330112372, 
                    "min" : 14.169602267136362, 
                    "mean" : "14.327042292326766"
                }
            },
        }
    }
    }];


// looking for how I can take my json data and dynamically pass it // to highcharts.
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Chart Example'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['SFA','IRB','IRB','SFA','IRB']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'EXAMPLE CHART'
            }
        },

       
        series: [
        
        // sfa data here
        
        {
          //this is sfa case 1 mean values in N_S direction
            name: 'SFA CASE 1 NS',
            data: [[0,8,],[0,8], [3,4]],

        }, 
        {
          //this is sfa case 1 mean values in S_N direction
            name: 'SFA CASE 1 SN',
            data: [[0,8],[0,8], [3,8]],

        }, 
        {
          //this is sfa case 2 mean values in N_S direction
            name: 'SFA CASE 2 NS',
            data: [[0,8,],[0,8], [3,4]],

        }, 
        {
          //this is sfa case 2 mean values in SN direction
            name: 'SFA CASE 2 SN',
            data: [[0,8],[0,8], [3,8]],

        }, 
        {
          //this is sfa case 3 mean values in N_S direction
            name: 'SFA CASE 3 NS',
            data: [[0,8,],[0,8], [3,4]],

        }, 
        {
          //this is sfa case 3 mean values in S_N direction
            name: 'SFA CASE 3 SN',
            data: [[0,8],[0,8], [3,8]],

        }, 
        
        
        // irb data here
        {
          //this is irb case 1 mean values in N_S direction
            name: 'IRB CASE 1 NS',
            data: [[1,6],[2,3],[4,4]],
            color: '#d111b7'

        },
        {
          //this is irb case 1 mean values in S_N direction
            name: 'IRB CASE 1 SN',
            data: [[1,6],[2,3],[4,4]],
            color: '#d111b7'

        },
        {
          //this is irb case 2 mean values in N_S direction
            name: 'IRB CASE 2 NS',
            data: [[1,6],[2,3],[4,4]],
            color: '#5e0853'

        },
        {
          //this is sfa case 2 mean values in S_N direction
            name: 'IRB CASE 2 SN',
            data: [[1,6],[2,3],[4,4]],
            color: '#330b2e'

        },
        {
        
          //this is irb case 3 mean values in N_S direction
            name: 'IRB CASE 3 NS',
            data: [[1,6],[2,3],[4,4]],
            color: '#785d75'

        },
        {
        
          //this is irb case 3 mean values in S_N direction
            name: 'IRB CASE 3 SN',
            data: [[1,6],[2,3],[4,4]],
            color: '#fa6eea'

        },
        

        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>

</figure>
```

Comment: I am having a little trouble trying to understand exactly what your requirements are - could you possibly produce an image of what you expect the final chart to look like?  It doesn't have to be exact - but would help in trying to visualise what your expected output should be. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sure let me see if I get a better visual representation.

Comment: I added a picture its still in the problem state but let me try to describe the issue and what Im looking for better. If you see in the pic I have a single entry for IRB data and I want that data to go to the IRB category but its getting lumped into the first entry of the graph. basically just looking for a multi category graph where I can put SFA data into one category and IRB data into another category. the JSfiddle is also here for the pic I created https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/kc9fhx1a/15/

Comment: I updated my picture of what I am trying to do and put that in a static jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/Lkbrnqyo/51/ hopefully it makes a bit more sense now with this new information.

Comment: Hi @Matt, You need to get the data that you want to show and convert it to the format required by Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that is actually what Im asking for help on how to take my JSON data and process it so I can pass that to highcharts in the order I described in my general problem.

Comment: Your data structure is complex are you unable to change it?

Comment: I could probably do that, but do you have a suggestion on what you think would make it less complex?

Comment: I would suggest a format as close as possible to the structure of the series. `[{ name: string, data: [[x, y], ...] }, ...]`